# Designing a better logger class

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, locking

Could you please critisize the logger class below? Can it be used in a multi threaded web environment? If not how can I improve it? Is there anything wrong with locking in WriteToLog method or multithreading in FlushLog method?

```
public class Logger
{
    private static Logger instance;
    private static Queue<LogData> logQueue;
    private static string logDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDirectory"]);
    private static string logFile = "log.txt";
    private static int maxLogAge = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogMaxAge"]);
    private static int queueSize = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogQueueSize"]);
    private static DateTime LastFlushed = DateTime.Now;

    private Logger() { }

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Logger();
                logQueue = new Queue<LogData>();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void WriteToLog(string message)
    {
        lock (logQueue)
        {
            LogData logEntry = new LogData(message);
            logQueue.Enqueue(logEntry);

            if (logQueue.Count >= queueSize || DoPeriodicFlush())
            {
                FlushLog();
            }
        }            
    }

    private bool DoPeriodicFlush()
    {
        TimeSpan logAge = DateTime.Now - LastFlushed;
        if (logAge.TotalSeconds >= maxLogAge)
        {
            LastFlushed = DateTime.Now;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void FlushLog()
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(q => {
            while (logQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                LogData entry = logQueue.Dequeue();
                string logPath = logDir + entry.LogDate + "_" + logFile;

                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logPath, true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", entry.LogTime, entry.Message));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
        FlushLog();
    }
}

public class LogData
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string LogTime { get; set; }
    public string LogDate { get; set; }

    public LogData(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        LogDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LogTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff tt");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel; use log4net.

Comment: This particular wheel has been invented multiple times. I suggest you take a look at one of the several options available.

Comment: With worries like these you should be using something like log4net where all of these issues have been worked out: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: Your code is rather non-thread-safe.

Comment: Might get more interest at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you haven't put it there yet.

Comment: As said in the comments, you should take a look at log4net. It's thread-safe and a proven solution. Features: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html NuGet package: https://nuget.org/packages/log4net/

Comment: Thanks @Gyhth. I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Please tell my mistakes. I know about log4net and the others. I just need to see some suggestions with your reasons to overcome my misunderstandings about the subject I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not thread safe.  You synchronize (lock) while adding to the queue, but your code which removes from the code does not lock the queue, and will always run on a background thread, which is going to cause potential race conditions.

If you really must write your own logging, I would, at the least, look into using [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to avoid the need for locking on adding.  `BlockingCollection<T>` would make this far simpler, as you could just have a thread call `GetConsumingEnumerable()` to process items as they're added.

That being said, logging is something that's been handled many times, and handled well.  You'd be far better off using something like the new [Semantic Logging Application Block](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/101823) (from P&P) or even [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm gonna take a look at your suggestions. I did not even know the classes you mentioned.

Comment: @anilca Great - that being said, for logging, using a pre-made solution is really just about always a superior option.